# How to create multiple cross-references in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, cross-reference

I would like to create several cross-references from lot of words to an only word at the same time.

For instance:

> My text: Blah blah *word* blah blah *word'* blah blah blah *word''* blah
>
> The cross reference that I woult like: *word word' word'' → wordDefinition*
>
> *wordDefinition* is in another page of the document.

Previously, I create one-by-one the cross-references, but now I'm having the problem of a lot of terminology pointing to the word definition. I would like to point all the instances of a term to its definition.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I know Microsoft Word fairly well, and I cannot understand your question.  Can you please try to explain it a different way?  Can you describe what you normally do, and what you have tried to solve this problem?  I know you don’t have enough reputation points on Super User to post images, but can you make an illustrative screen image and put it on a web server where we can look at it?

Comment: I’m sorry, but I _still_ don’t understand what you are saying.

Comment: They are identical. But both possibilities are interesting.